# Python setuptools - no module named after pip install

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to create python CLI using click project and I have problems with packaging it. I created my script in `mycli.py` file like this

```
import click

from module1 import Service1


@click.group()
def mycli():
    pass

@mycli.command()
def dosth():
    click.echo(Service1().dosth())
...
```

My directory tree looks like this

```
mycli/
├── __init__.py
├── module1
├── module2
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── mycli.py
└── venv
```

I added setup.py like

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='mycli',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'click==8.1.3',
        ...
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "mycli = mycli:mycli"
        ]
    },
)
```

And my requirements.txt looks like

```
.
```

I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and then I try to run `mycli` and I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/clydebarrow/Documents/IdeaProjects/mycli/venv/bin/mycli", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('mycli==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'mycli')())
  File "/Users/clydebarrow/Documents/IdeaProjects/mycli/venv/bin/mycli", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 86, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mycli'
```

How to solve it ? Thanks

Comment: A requirements.txt file containing `.` is a strange thing to me. Have you tried `pip install -e .` instead?

Comment: But I think the problem is with your directory structure. I would have `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` in the parent directory of the `mycli` directory, and run `pip install -e .` in that parent directory.

Comment: Yep I did what you suggested and it's working thank you ! I am quite new to python I didn't know how to structure the directory properly - once again thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your directory structure.

You should have `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` in the parent directory of the `mycli` directory, and run `pip install -e .` in that parent directory.

Comment: Upgrading my comment to an answer since OP said it solved the problem.